# trying to consolidate all require files into one file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

Fir the longest time I have been having to require every file i need to use at the top of of every file that needs to use said file like so:

```
var moduleAPartOne = require('./module.a.one.js');
var moduleAPartTwo = require('./module.a.two.js');
var moduleAPartThree = require('./module.a.three.js');
```

In a large scale application this makes maintaining and making changes to the structure of the app down the road a hassle.

I am trying to put all these file requires into a single file which other files can call like so:

```
// a.module.js
module.exports = {
    aOne: require('./a.one.js'),
    aTwo: require('./a.two.js'),
    aThree: require('./a.three.js')
}


// then in my other files elsewhere in the app
var aModule = require('a/a.module.js');
```

The object I expect to get out of this is:

```
aModule = {
    aOne: { // some stuff... },
    aTwo: { // some stuff... },
    aThree: { // some stuff... }
}
```

instead I get:

```
aModule = {};
```

What do I need to do in order for aModule to be populated with properties and methods created in the files it required?

Comment: Make sure a.one.js exports something

Comment: Seems this is being caused a different issue. its actually a circular dependency which is causing the problem. So I am searching a solution for that.